# how to get updated live data to variables passed through constructor?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-getx

i'm struggling to find a solution to my issue, i hope you guys can help.

in (PAGE 1) i have Streambuilder and i'm forwarding data to (PAGE 2) through the constructor and then to  (PAGE 3).

now (PAGE 1 receives stream of live data that updates whenever changes occur.

the problem here the data in (PAGE 2 & 3) don't listen to those updates.

now how can i make those data listen to updates. taking into account index is involved when passing those data.

NOTE: i'm using Getx for state management

thank you.

i can't find a way that works when index is involved

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, you need to provide code to get ourselves in the context of your problem, However, if you have a `StreamBuilder` that contains nested widgets, you can get the expected update in them, but navigating between pages using `Navigator`, will open each page as a sibling of the previous one in the `Navigator` tree, even if it is like that every page is child of the previous one, so you can't achieve your goal using a `StreamBuilder`.

Comment: You will need to learn and use features of a specific state manager, in your case you're using Getx, right? then you should better look to use a `GetxController` where the state and relations of those pages are, manage it from there and expose a state update using `GetBuilder`, `Obx`.. widgets

Comment: thank you for your reply, no code required here, i'm presenting a scenario , i am using Getx controller, but you cant use obx on values from listview builder, because it's based on index as i mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can solve that problem, rather than using `StreamBuilder` you can use `Rx` and `Obx` for continuous updates.

I provide you steps to start to implement like below:

**Step 1:** create a controller and add any variable using the `Rx` keyword.

**Step 2:** use the `Obx` widget where you want to listen to continuous updates.

now all three pages have an Obx widget so when you change the value, it listens on all three widgets.

Comment: thank you for your answer, that would work if index is not part of the equation . the data are passed based on index from list view builder.